# How can generate the 32-bit RISCV form chisel soure. What are the required modifications?

Tags: scala, chisel, riscv

According to the RISCV toolchain, we are generating the verilog files for Rocketchip as 64-bit. but we need 32-bit RISCV rocket chip. 
For that what are requirements and modifications in scala and chisel files.

Is it possible to generate the 32-bit Rocket core to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocket is a RV64 implementation. Unfortunately it does not have a simple switch to make it RV32. Making it RV32 will require some modification, hopefully small.

Comment: Could you give some details on possible areas in the architecture that need to be modify.

Comment: In addition to the usual places (register widths and decode), the most awkward part will be the HTIF, which does not have a 32-bit version.